# Shuffling Several DataFrames Together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to shuffle several DataFrames together?

For example I have a DataFrame `df1` and a DataFrame `df2`. I want to shuffle the rows randomly, but for both DataFrames in the same way.

**Example**

`df1`:

```
|___|_______|
| 1 |  ...  |
| 2 |  ...  |
| 3 |  ...  |
| 4 |  ...  |
```

`df2`:

```
|___|_______|
| 1 |  ...  |
| 2 |  ...  |
| 3 |  ...  |
| 4 |  ...  |
```

After shuffling a possible order for **both DataFrames** could be:

```
|___|_______|
| 2 |  ...  |
| 3 |  ...  |
| 4 |  ...  |
| 1 |  ...  |
```

Comment: I am assuming there is atleast one common column in both the dataframes?

Comment: @AnirudhSridhar: Just the index, but it has the same number of rows.

Comment: I think @jezrael's answer is the correct one. My approach would have involved merging the two dataframes, shuffling and then splitting them. That would ensure that both dataframes are shuffled identically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can double [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with applying [`numpy.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) to `index`, but is necessary both `DataFrame`s have same length and same unique index values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(5)})
print (df1)
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(5)})
print (df2)
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

idx = np.random.permutation(df1.index)
print (df1.reindex(idx))
   a
2  2
4  4
1  1
3  3
0  0

print (df2.reindex(idx))
   a
2  2
4  4
1  1
3  3
0  0
```

Alternative with [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
print (df1.reindex_axis(idx, axis=0))
print (df2.reindex_axis(idx, axis=0))
```

Comment: `.reindex_axis` will be removed in a future version and `.reindex` should be used instead.